# Whitelist SharePoint Online Hosted App?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services, security

The scenario is this:

- We have a Web Service which is hosted in Intranet Network
- Plan is to expose Web Service to Internet so SharePoint Online Hosted App can access it

Problem is security. If there is no authentication method for the Web Service, hackers can easily call Web Service if they know the URL.

Is there a way to 'whitelist' requests coming from SharePoint Online? And how do we know which IPs is it?

Does the SharePoint Hosted App even mark as originating from 'microsoft servers'? Or the App will have IP address originating from wherever the User is?

Thank you

Comment: You may create a add-in host in your on-premise server. Refer below thread  http://sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-Procedure-to-Create-a-Low-Trust-Provider-Hosted-App-for-Office-365-and-Host-the-AppWeb-in-Local-IIS

Answer (score 2):

Add Admin authentication to your web service.

Once that is done. Add a piece of code to your SharePoint hosted app to correctly authenticate your web service request.

In this way your service calls are always authenticated.